# Android slide ImageView from top to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to develop a game which has the track sliding down from the top to the bottom. When you start the track(which is a large image) is "out of screen" then it slides from the top and goes out at the bottom. The images might be very large, larger/taller than most screens.

I can animate the image with animations, but Android scales the image to the screen size on load, which I dont want. How can I keep the original size of the image?

I dont think using ScrollView would be good since I dont want the user to scroll the image.

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can use some of the ideas from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098083/how-to-animate-a-slide-in-notification-view-that-pushes-the-content-view-down/19098369#19098369

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix you could try to wrap you ImageView with an **AbsoluteLayout**. Check an answer to the question [How to create a view that is bigger than the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813049/how-to-create-a-view-that-is-bigger-than-the-screen#answer-3814580)

Be aware it's deprecated and for the stable future use you have to get another solution.