# How to make layout bigger than screen

Tags: android, layout, view

I want to create a View that will be bigger than screen height.

I want a view that will be `1080px x 4000px` after initialize. How to make this?

Comment: I would assume that a Sprite sheet would be best for this.  You can drop a huge graphic in there and define only what coords to show.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813049/how-to-create-a-view-that-is-bigger-than-the-screen

Comment: @AkbarRezaee i want to change view\layout in runtime.

Comment: you'll need to be more specific. Do you want to see all 1080x400 pixels at the same time? Or only a screen sized portion at a time? if so, Do you want to scroll/pan through that image?

Comment: @Martin I want to see only portion of view. And yes - i want to zoom & pan fuctions too.